# Why doesn't accessing a field through a property behave like directly accessing the field?

Tags: json, vbscript, properties

I found [this](http://www.aspjson.com/) nice class for parsing JSON in VBScript. On that page is an example of using the class. I use VbsEdit (because of its IntelliSense) for working with VBScript. However, when following the example given, I found that the public field called "data" was not appearing in the suggestion list.

[image]

This code works fine as-is but no IntelliSense:

```
Addr1 = oJSON.data("ShipToAddress")("AddressLine1")("value")
```

So I made the field private and added a public property and now it shows up in IntelliSense:

[image]

However, now I get an error when trying to access the data through the property:

```
Addr1 = oJSON.JSONdata("ShipToAddress")("AddressLine1")("value")
```

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error (7, 1) : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'oJSON.JSONdata'

The object type is Dictionary.  So I tried this:

```
For Each key In oJSON.JSONdata
    WScript.Echo key
Next
```

and I got all the top-level keys from the JSON string:

```
id
rowNumber
note
Approved
BaseCurrencyID
BillToAddressOverride
BillToContactOverride
CashAccount
ControlTotal
CreditHold
CurrencyID
CurrencyRate
CurrencyRateTypeID
CustomerID
CustomerOrder
Date
Description
DestinationWarehouseID
Details
EffectiveDate
ExternalRef
Hold
IsTaxValid
LastModified
LocationID
NewCard
OrderedQty
OrderNbr
OrderTotal
OrderType
PaymentCardIdentifier
PaymentMethod
PaymentRef
PreAuthorizationNbr
PreAuthorizedAmount
ReciprocalRate
RequestedOn
ShippingSettings
ShipToAddress
ShipToAddressOverride
ShipToContact
ShipToContactOverride
ShipVia
Status
TaxTotal
custom
files
```

But if I try to access any of the keys in the dictionary, I get the error shown above.

Is there some reason I don't know about why it doesn't work through a property?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you modified the behaviour of an established JSON parsing library because the intellisence didn't work as expected in a 3rd party editor?

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing more of the class, [found this online](https://github.com/zhennanzhuce/js/blob/master/js/ueditor/1.4.3/asp/ASPJson.class.asp) but this one may be different. It's likely something to do with it being an object reference and needing to have a `Property Set JSONdata` as well as the `Property Get JSONdata`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment using classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27093706/692942)

Comment: Lankymart - yes that is the one I'm using although I got it from the author's website (link is in my question).

Comment: Lankymart - to answer your first question, yes. I wanted IntelliSense to work with it.  I didn't use the Set property because data is only being set from inside the class.  I'm using the class now as it was written because it doesn't work using the property. My question is why.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate question. I already read that question and answer and it doesn't fit my scenario. I don't need indexed access. I just wanted to retrieve the object via the property.

Comment: But you get the exact same error regardless.

Comment: Try changing your `Public Property Get JSONdata()` to pass a single `key` as an argument.  For example, `Public Property Get JSONdata(key) Set JSONdata = data(key) End Property`  Otherwise, try changing `Addr1 = oJSON.JSONdata("ShipToAddress")("AddressLine1")("value")` call to `Addr1 = (oJSON.JSONdata())("ShipToAddress")("AddressLine1")("value")`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @leeharvey1 but that isn't what is happening the `JSONdata` property is just an object reference to the `Scripting.Dictionary`, the `JSONdata("ShipToAddress")` is just the default method on the Dictionary being called `JSONdata.Item("ShipToAddress")` not sure what adding the indexer does different.